# Flutter: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' in SharedPreference

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

How to pass the parameter getString need String? but read() used String

```
class SharedPref {
  read(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return json.decode(prefs.getString(key)); // the error in this line
  }
```

this is for sharedPreferences of flutter. how to solve this?

Comment: Use a null-assertion (!), Duplicate  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68059638/4623392

Comment: But you have to make sure then, that prefs.getString(key) does not return null

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```dart
return json.decode(prefs.getString(key) ?? '');
// or
return prefs.getString(key) != null ? json.decode(prefs.getString(key)) : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `prefs.getString(key)` returns a `String?`. It means that can return a String or a null value. You have to ensure that the value will not be null when passed to `json.decode()`.

Check out the [documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code

```
read(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? str = prefs.getString(key) ?? '';
    return json.decode(str); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's cause of `getString` method have return type `String?`

```
  /// Reads a value from persistent storage, throwing an exception if it's not a
  /// String.
  String? getString(String key) => _preferenceCache[key] as String?;
```

But `json.decode` takes `String` as parameter

```
  /// Parses the string and returns the resulting Json object.
  ///
  /// The optional [reviver] function is called once for each object or list
  /// property that has been parsed during decoding. The `key` argument is either
  /// the integer list index for a list property, the string map key for object
  /// properties, or `null` for the final result.
  ///
  /// The default [reviver] (when not provided) is the identity function.
  dynamic decode(String source,
      {Object? reviver(Object? key, Object? value)?}) {
    reviver ??= _reviver;
    if (reviver == null) return decoder.convert(source);
    return JsonDecoder(reviver).convert(source);
  }
```

So you must pass `String` into `json.decode` method. There are many ways to do this

```
// prefs.getString(key) return null, use '' as parameter
return json.decode(prefs.getString(key) ?? ''); 
// or
// throw exception when prefs.getString(key) return null. 
// Wrap your method with `try ... catch ... `
return json.decode(prefs.getString(key)!);
```